# getting the ajax output with out parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a jquery - ajax request running, it provides output in json format. If my guess is correct, The ajax response that we get is parsed one. I would like to get the original raw data i.e. the response without parsing. Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you done a `console.log` of the value `j`? I'm sure the .ajex method returns a string (or whatever your code returns) and it's up to you to either do an `eval` or parse it to get a javascript object

Comment: no ajax request gives us a parsed output..

Answer (score 4):

Remove `dataType : "json",` or change it to `dataType : "text",` or simply access the `responseText` property of the [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) (depending on what you want to do with the data).

For more detailed information, *read the documentation*: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: Well, I gave you a third option, access `responseText` ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're 100% sure you're getting a JavaScript object back (I've always parsed my return from a `$.ajax()` method), then you'll need to **stringify** your object.

See: http://www.json.org/js.html

And here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js to download the "json.js" file.

With this file you can `parse` and `stringify` as needed.

So, to get the text version, you would do:

```
var sObj = JSON.stringify(j);
console.log(sObj);
```

However, from what I have read, you will need to parse the return object:

> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter;

So it is formatted as a JSON "string", which will still need to be parsed or (quick and dirty) `eval`'d